# I want to integrate code coverage for a javascript api project (build with node and express)

Tags: express, mocha.js, supertest, istanbul, should.js

This is the open sorce project https://github.com/telepat-io. I want to attach integration testing with code coverage. The tests are build with mocha an should.js . I have tried istanbul, codeclever, blanket, grunt. nothing worked. They all give me code coverage reports with 0% coverage. i am testing the routes and responses. I would also would like to integrate with travis.
I have tests looking like this:

```
        describe('Admin', function() {

        it('should return a 200 code to indicate succes when creating a new admin', function(done) {

            // once we have specified the info we want to send to the server via POST verb,
            // we need to actually perform the action on the resource, in this case we want to 
            // POST on /api/profiles and we want to send some info
            // We do this using the request object, requiring supertest!
            request(url)
            .post('/admin/add')
            .send(admin)
            // end handles the response
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                    done(err);
                }

                  // this is should.js syntax, very clear
                res.statusCode.should.be.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });
 });
```

P.S. istanbul gives me a No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

Comment: Can you share the command line you use to run your tests and coverage ?

Comment: npm install -g istanbul
    istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec
    open coverage/lcov-report/index.html

Comment: I suppose the test that you specified don't cover anything. It just makes request to the remote server. Istanbul can't guess which lines of code were executed at the server.

Comment: the test cover the routes and they are integration test. by doing a admin/add folowed by an admin/me request i test: the routes, the writer, CRUD operations, etc...

Comment: Yes, but the code under test is running at the server and istanbul has no info of what code is executed there. I just found out that there is istanbul-middleware for code coverage in functional tests: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul-middleware